# JavaScript hebrew CSV parsing issue

Tags: javascript, csv, encoding, papaparse

so i got a csv file saves as CSV -UTF-8 file from excel
on the right its in visual studio on the left its in excel.

when im trying to parse with PapaParse/csv-parser, i still see the output in <?> format
which it means encoding :
PapaParse try:

```
 papa.parse(file, {
    worker: true, 
    step: function (result) {
       count++; 
       console.log(result.data[0])
    },
    complete: function (results, file) {//
       console.log('parsing complete read', count, 'records.');
    }
});
```

csv-reader try:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const results = [];
fs.createReadStream('Cities.csv')
   .pipe(csv())
   .on('data', function (datarow) {
       results.push(datarow);
   })
   .on('end', function () {
       console.log(results.toString('utf-8");
   });
```

In both situations the output is in <?> cant read hebrew chars

Comment: May you share an example of the csv file?

Comment: the csv example is in the image ? what else you need to see

Comment: Not an image. I cannot copy paste text from an image.

Comment: how can i upload the file

Comment: Re @evolutionxbox's point about the data example: Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: There is no error message just the output is unreadable with strange characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not because of the code, but because of the console properties. I had to change the font so that the console can display the Hebrew letters correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you're piping the raw chunk buffers to `csv`, not the result of converting to string using UTF-8 encoding. You aren't telling `createReadStream` to handle any encoding work for you, so it will read raw data and pass them to the `csv` function (since you're piping to it) as `Buffer` instances.

Rather than reading raw data and converting afterward, tell `createReadStream` you want it to handle conversion for you via its [options parameter](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options):

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const results = [];
fs.createReadStream('Cities.csv', 'utf-8')
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^
   .pipe(csv())
   .on('data', function (datarow) {
       results.push(datarow);
   })
   .on('end', function () {
       // Use `results` here (it's an array of objects according to the
       // csv-parser documentation; calling `toString` on it probably isn't
       // what you want)
   });
```

Comment: nice solution, but the main problem was with my console properties , case closed , thanks!

Comment: @BenCohen - Ah! It was nagging at me that the `csv-parser` lib wouldn't be using `Buffer.prototype.toString`, which defaults to `utf-8` anyway... :-) Still, best to be explicit rather than implicit. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @BenCohen - Probably worth posting that as an answer, rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add this:

format:"UTF-8"

```
   papa.parse(file, {
        worker: true, 
        step: function (result) {
           count++; 
           console.log(result.data[0])
        },
       format: "UTF-8"
        complete: function (results, file) {//
           console.log('parsing complete read', count, 'records.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe do you have a problem with your file?

Comment: I cant see a problem with my csv file . all looks good.